# Character encoding between java and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, utf-8

I have a problem while inserting data from java jdbc to MySQL database, from a generated .jar file.

"Ñ" characters turns '?' in the table.

Things I tried without good results:

- Adding useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=utf8 in drivermanager URL
- Changing character set to utf8 anD collation to utf8_unicode_ci

When I run the program in Eclipse IDE with ISO-8859-1 configuration works OK and put the correct characters into database, but when I run the .jar file in my system (Ubuntu 16 with UTF-8), '?' characters appears instead of 'Ñ'in the MySQL database.

Is there any solution?
(I know is possible that this question will be a duplicated question, but other questions I found they haven't worked for me)

Comment: What MySQL client are you using?

Comment: Are you indeed offering "Ñ" to the database? If you read the text from file, that file should be read with (my guess) ISO-8859-1 (or better Cp1252). I think a file/resource is read with the default encoding, and a placeholder turned into a question mark.

Comment: shmosel I'm using MySQL WorkBench and MySQL version is 14.14

Comment: Joop Eggen, I'm reading teh data from another database (using select and then putting the resultset into an insert into statement)

Comment: Joop Eggen If I put a 'Ñ' letter directly in the table it's appears OK

Comment: @JohnStonecutter - If you run your jar file with `java -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 -jar your.jar` does it work any better? (p.s. Remember to use "@" when you reply like I just did.)

Comment: See "question mark" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Thanks @Rick James